# How is the running time calculated for nested "for" loops?

Tags: algorithm, performance, timing, notation

Recently started with this so need your help, Lets say you have nested for loops as shown below, both ranging from 1 to n, how does one calculate the running time for the same in terms of Big O, Theta, Omega?

```
for(i=1; i<n; i++) {
    for(j=1; j<n; j++) {
       //some piece of code
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you think of a way to count the exact number of times that `//some piece of code` is executed?

Comment: Implement it and just try it for different values of `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for(i=1; i<n; i++) {
     for(j=1; j<n; j++) {
       //some piece of code
      }
  }
```

So let's look closer at this piece of code. Say we have a set of 10 items (n) and we execute these loops one by one. First it has to pass the i loop. he'll pas it for 1, then that 1 goes into the second loop 10 times before 1 becomes 2. In total it has to pass loop 100 times before reaching the end. In big O notation, we always calculate O for the worst case scenario. That is, needing an item that is at the end of your loop. Say we add 1 to n. How many times it has to pass the loop now? 11 * 11 and that is 121. So whenever your input grows 1, the cost of this algorithm grows exponentially. That is why we say O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, all of them is the same, as there is no logic:

- First loop: `1..N`, N iterations, `O(N)` (same for the other two)
- Second loop: Same, `1..N`, `O(N)`

So, `O(N*N)` => `O(N^2)`.

About the theta one, I'm not used to use it, so maybe someone can extend the answer. But I think it's the same